# Синтаксис задания высоты блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Есть интерфейсные блоки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть блок в коде

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commons.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subcategory.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components.bundle.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles__ltr.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic" media="all">



  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sitestyles.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  @media (screen or handheld) and (max-width:375) {
  <div class="headerpart">
  </div>
  }
</body>
```

375 - это ширина всего блока mobile view. А высота всего блока mobile view - 3311px, высота блока с текстом Обзоры - 172px. Как задать высоту блока с текстом Обзоры в следующем виде - (172/3311)*высотаокна в css?

```css
.headerpart {
    width: 100%;
    height: (172/3311)*body.height;
}
```

Последний код по смыслу верен, но синтаксически скорее всего нет.

Comment: `(172/3311)*высотаокна в css` никак на css, тут нужен js

Comment: @InDevX вариант (172/3311)*высотаокна не существует как я понял. А вообще есть ли хоть какие-то способы в css задания высоты блока относительно высоты другого?

Comment: Если это 2 совершенно не связанных блока то нет, не существует. То что вы хотите можно реализовать на js добавив resize event, проверять width окна, если она соответствует условию - задать height по вашей формуле

Comment: @InDevX я не понял. Открыл новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270595/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0 - пишите в нем.

Comment: я ничего не понял, а (17200/3311)vh - это не то?

Comment: @splash58 так, очевидно же, высота body может быть больше видимых 100 vh

Comment: А вы хотите объяснить, для чего Вам это? Может быть решение есть проще...

Comment: @itspec891 в данной вёрстке вам не нужно указывать размеры высоты фиксированно для всего контейнера. Просто делаете в контейнере блок с контентом (там даже высоту не надо давать) и элементы сами будут друг друга отодвигать