# События изменения ширины и высоты окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Каков синтаксис события изменения

1. ширины окна и
2. высоты окна?
3. в javascript;
4. в jquery?
   По изменению ширины и высоты окна должно происходить пропорциональное изменения ширины и высоты блока относительно всего окна (см. [Синтаксис задания высоты блока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270566/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)).

Comment: есть одно событие - изменение размера. а пропорциональные размеры можно задать с помощью процентов в стилях

Comment: @teran можно пример кода, а то на словах не понятно (я новичок).

Comment: @itspec891 jquery не советую изучать, только если вы хотите получать мало деняк

Answer (score 3):

Событие изменения окна:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Изменение ширины и высоты элементов в зависимости от ширины и высоты окна браузера на JS:

```js
const block = document.querySelector('.block');
resizeWindow(block);

window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  resizeWindow(block);
});

function resizeWindow(block) {
  
  block.style.width = `${window.innerWidth / 3}px`;
  block.style.height = `${window.innerHeight / 3}px`;
  block.innerHTML = `
  <p>window.innerWidth: ${window.innerWidth}</p>
  <p>window.innerHeight: ${window.innerHeight}</p>
  `;
}
```

```css
.block {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Событие изменения размеров элемента:

```js
const widthDom = document.querySelector('#width');
const heightDom = document.querySelector('#height');
const textboxDom = document.querySelector('#textbox');

function outputsize() {
 widthDom.value = textboxDom.offsetWidth;
 heightDom.value = textboxDom.offsetHeight;
}
outputsize();

new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(textboxDom);
```

```html
Width: <output id="width">0</output><br>
Height: <output id="height">0</output><br>
<textarea id="textbox">Отресайзь меня полностью</textarea><br>
```

Задание высоты и ширины блока от ширины и высоты окна браузера на CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```